# Laravel Eloquent: sum with groupBy

Tags: sql, eloquent

Need eloquent/fluent query to get sum with groupBy function.

So far I have tried:

```
    $this->data['no_of_pages'] = Document::sum('no_of_pages')
                                ->groupBy('users_editor_id');
```

Which ofcourse gives me `call to member function groupBy() on non-object` because of the fact that sum() will already execute the query and have result ready by the time grouBy() is applied. So can anyone guide me?

Answer (score 87, accepted):

```
Document::groupBy('users_editor_id')
   ->selectRaw('sum(no_of_pages) as sum, users_editor_id')
   ->pluck('sum','users_editor_id');

   // originally lists(), which was deprecated in favour of pluck in 5.2
   // and dropped completely in 5.3
   // ->lists('sum','users_editor_id');


// returns array like this:
array(
  users_editor_id => sum,
  ...
)
```

Or this way (which I wouldn't use, since it won't be actual ORM result):

```
Document::groupBy('users_editor_id')
   ->selectRaw('*, sum(no_of_pages) as sum')
   ->get();

// returns collection of Document pseudo models with additional sum field
```

Comment: Note: `->lists()` has been renamed `->pluck()` since laravel 5.2.

Comment: Hi. This doesn't work with calculated attributes like "getTotalAttribute" method in the Model.

Answer (score 10):

```
Document::Where('some_condition',true)
   ->select([DB::raw("SUM(debit) as total_debit"), DB::raw("SUM(credit) as total_credit")])
   ->groupBy('id')
   ->get()
```

Answer (score 7):

Little bit refactored and convenient answer is (from @keroles Monsef)

```
Document::Where('some_condition',true)
    ->selectRaw("SUM(debit) as total_debit")
    ->selectRaw("SUM(credit) as total_credit")
    ->groupBy('id')
    ->get();
```

Comment: How to sum total_debit and total_credit as say(total_amount) in same query?

Comment: It's Simple you think little bit: `selectRaw("SUM(credit) + SUM(debit) as total_amount")`

Comment: No in my case I want to sum total_debit and total_credit not the columns(credit and debit)
I have count the user by status as total_active and total_inactive now i want to sum these total_active and total_inactive with selectRaw

Comment: Could you provide Sql-query info/example like:https://www.mycompiler.io/view/EWGZqc5CS61