# get sum of all the transactions of each user for specific month

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-query-builder

I am working on small finance web app and I need to generate one monthly general report of all the users which shows a total of all the transactions made by each user during a month. the table structure is as below.

```
username    amount  date
-----------------------------
a           1000    2018-8-1
b           2000    2018-8-1
c           1500    2018-8-3
b           1700    2018-8-6
b           1100    2018-8-7
a           2000    2018-8-10
c           1600    2018-8-12
```

Need to get sum of each user's transactions during the month such as

```
a : 3000
b : 4800
c : 3100
```

Please help me to find out the sum using `laravel query builder`.

Comment: Have you tried writing any Laravel code yet?  Here is one SO answer which you can probably use right away: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24887708/laravel-eloquent-sum-with-groupby

Comment: Thanks @TimBiegeleisen it's work for me.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Laravel Eloquent: sum with groupBy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24887708/laravel-eloquent-sum-with-groupby)

Answer (score -1):

You can do this :

```
$user
->transactions()
->where('date', '>', Carbon::before())
->where('date', '<', Carbon::now())
->get(['user_id', 'amount'])
->sum('amount');
```

This considering you have a relationship between transactions and user models. You can adapt to your schema. But the pure MySQL solution that @Tim Biegeleisen linked may be more resources efficient.

You may also use `whereBetween()`, but check that it works correctly with dates.

Comment: This does not specify a specific month.

Comment: Oups sorry, I forgot the date query. I updated my answer. Carbon dates are examples of course.