# Did use sum of sum with groupby in Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

Alreay i sum the column price groupby inventory_id .Additionally i need to calculate total price.

```
$record = ProductDetails::with('inventoryName')->whereDate('created_at', '=', date($date))
      ->select('inventory_id',DB::raw('sum(price) as item_price'),DB::raw('sum(quantity) as quantity'))->groupBy('inventory_id')->get();
```

My **output** is :

```
[
  {
    inventory_id: 9,
    item_price: 30,
    quantity: 30,
    inventory_name: [
      {
        id: 9,
        name: "sugar"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    inventory_id: 10,
    item_price: 70,
    quantity: 70,
    inventory_name: [
      {
        id: 10,
        name: "oil"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Now i need to calculate total price.How to do this.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Laravel Eloquent: sum with groupBy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24887708/laravel-eloquent-sum-with-groupby)

Comment: Do you want `total price = (item_1_price * item_1_quantity) +(item_2_price * item_2_quantity) +...` ?

Comment: No i need to caluculate sum of total item_price

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Laravel Collection: SUM method](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/collections#method-sum).

```
1. If $record is already a collection:
echo $record->sum('item_price');

2. If $record is an array.
$collection = collect($record);
$collection->sum('item_price');
```