# List of users with the highest sum of points

Tags: laravel

I would like to create a ranking ordered by the user who has the most "points" scored.

My "points" table has these fields: user_id, type and quantity.

[image]

In this example, user 1 has a total of 4 points, while user 2 has a total of 8.

My dilemma after several unsuccessful tests, is to create a cycle that shows users with the highest sum of "quantity".

How can I do?

Comment: what you have tried so far?

Comment: Nothing in particular unfortunately, I can not find a logic of how to behave, I am stuck.

Comment: Thank you very much, I have tried and apparently it work!

Comment: Have also a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24887708/laravel-eloquent-sum-with-groupby

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to use `selectRaw(sum(columan) as total)` then `group`

```php
Point::selectRaw("SUM(quantity) as total_quantity,user_id")->groupBy('user_id')->get()
```