# How to sum of column in laravel with relationship

Tags: laravel, eloquent

[image]

How to sum of duration column where my course id or section id is same

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use hasMany relation on this table with course and section table.
For hasMany relation see this docs. [Here](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships)

Then, you can use foreach to generate the sum.

```
$summation = $yourtablenames->sum(function ($yourtablename) {
    return $yourtablename->your_relation_name->sum('duration');
});
```

Comment: what is your $yourtablenames and what is $yourtablename. my engine can not find $yourtablenames.

Comment: that is your database table or model name based on how you get data from database

Comment: You're not even giving us your table/model's name, so people just use other naming for the variable. It's just an usual variable. @AlShahriarMehedi

Comment: my model name is (App\Models\Lesson)Lesson and table name is lessons.Now how can I calculate and print this.Please share...

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
$res = Model::groupBy('course_id', 'section_id')
   ->selectRaw('sum(duration) as total_duration, course_id, section_id') // do the sum query here
   ->pluck('total_duration','course_id', 'section_id'); // get the related query column here
```

[Source answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24887708/laravel-eloquent-sum-with-groupby)

Comment: When I try to print this $res then I got an array. How can I print this sum by using dd?

Comment: Inside that array, it has the property named `total_duration`. That is what you're looking for.