# How to get Sum of records according to company in laravel using eloquent

Tags: laravel, eloquent

These are given data

```
No CompanyName Price
 1     A       $2.5
 2     B       $5.1
 3     C       $10
 4     A       $1.3
 5     A       $5.1
 6     B       $2.5
 7     B       $2.3
 8     C       $2.3

Expecting Result
Company  Price
  A        $2.5 + $1.3 + $5.1
  B        $5.1 + $2.5 + $2.3
  C        $10 + $2.3
```

How can I get this result using laravel eloquent

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Laravel Eloquent: sum with groupBy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24887708/laravel-eloquent-sum-with-groupby)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ModelName::groupBy('CompanyName')
   ->selectRaw('*, sum(Price) as sum')
   ->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

I am note sure if I got your question right, but I think you want the sum of all columns where the company name is for example `A`

You can get it this way:

```
DB::table('your_table')->where('CompanyName', '=', 'desired_name')->sum(price);
```

So you put in the name of your table in `'your_table'` - then you pick those out `where` the `CompanyName`matches the company you are looking for (`desired_name'`) and calculate the `sum`of `price`

Comment: If follow your way, I don't get result with only one command.
I want to get result without "desired_name".
I want to get sum of records according to all company,
Any other way?

Comment: @Qingri you can make a separate query for each company and replace desired_name with the name of the company.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `groupBy`.

```
Model::query()->select('company_name', DB::raw('SUM(price) as total_price'))->groupBy('company_name')->get();
```

And if you want to add conditions to this result, you can use `having` like this:

```
Model::query()->select('company_name', DB::raw('SUM(price) as total_price'))->groupBy('company_name')->having('total_price', '>', 100)->get();
```