# Laravel group by weekday and get total count

Tags: laravel

To get the total number of orders by weekday, I use:

```php
Order::select('*')
  ->get()
  ->groupBy(function($date) {
    return Carbon::parse($date->created_at)->format('l');
  });
```

What I would like to add is that it returns, per weekday, the count of the items that were ordered, which is a property on the Order model called `item_count`. I tried using `sum()` on the query but that doesn't work.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Laravel Eloquent: sum with groupBy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24887708/laravel-eloquent-sum-with-groupby)

Comment: No that gives `Call to a member function groupBy() on string`. Maybe because in my case the `groupBy` is a function?

Answer (score 0):

This was the solution:

```php
Order::select(
    DB::raw('DAYNAME(created_at) AS week_day'),
    DB::raw('WEEKDAY(created_at) as day'),
    DB::raw("SUM(item_count) as items_total")
  )
  ->orderBy('day')
  ->groupBy(DB::raw('DAYNAME(created_at)'))
  ->get();
```